# older blog posts not showing in new theme

Tags: posts, loop, blog

I have a new, custom theme that I've uploaded on a pre-existing site/blog. Everything seems to be working ok, with the exception of the older blog posts not showing up. Any ideas what I can do to fix?

```
<?php get_header();?>

<div id="blog-container">
    <?php get_sidebar( 'blog');?>
    <div class="content">
    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(''); ?>
        <div class="meta">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <p><span style="font-size:85%"><?php the_tags('tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?> | <?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?> comments</span></p>
        </div><!-- end meta -->
        <div class="post">
            <?php the_content('read more...'); ?>
        </div><!-- end post -->
        <div class="share">
            <span class="left-border"></span><!-- end border -->
            <p style="font-family:nevis-webfont;">SHARE THIS POST</p>
            <span class="right-border"></span><!-- end border -->
        </div><!-- end share -->
    </div><!-- end content -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
            <p>I'm not sure what you're looking for.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- end blog-container -->

<?php get_footer();?>
```

***eta*** Finally got the posts to show by cleaning up the code, however they are now all jumbled. How can I remedy this?

Comment: Your blog posts index is displaying all 40 posts: http://frshstudio.com/blog/

Comment: I'd keep the 'query_posts' in the question, if i were you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What posts exactly are not shown?
In your code there are no page links (pagination).
Could it be that you just see the the number of posts according to the respective admin setting?

In addition, I just have been learned NOT to use `query_posts`. Why would you use it there anyway? Assuming, this is a post-showing template (e.g., index, front-page), you just have to write:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
DO YOUR POST STUFF
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I've just removed `query_posts`, and am still unable to see the 40 posts pre-existing on this site. Just updated my original code to reflect what is currently on my site. Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: So, I take it you have set the number of posts in the admin settings to 40, right?

Comment: No, the number of posts I currently have set to show in Settings - Reading is 1000(changed just to rule out any issues in the Settings). However, the number of posts I have actually made is only 40.

Comment: Okay, and how many posts of the existing 40 DO you see?

Comment: I don't see any, that's my problem. Sorry, I thought I linked to my site, it's http://frshstudio.com.. maybe that will help.

Comment: Well, there is no closing <a> tag in your HOME heading, but that's not the point here. Maybe you could check line-by-line what is not working as it should. Do you have set the blog page in the admin settings? Otherwise you, of course, have to do a query of your own. Try print_r(query_posts($args));. What does the output look like?

Comment: Please add `<php body_class(); ?>` to the HTML `<body>` tag, and wrap your post output in `<div <?php post_class(); ?>></div>` for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `query_posts()`. It is causing your pagination problem.

For more detailed information, [see this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts).

For alternatives when you need to modify the main loop query, or add secondary queries, [see this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

### Edit

Based on your edit removing `query_posts()`, your next issue is that you don't provide any navigation links.

Here's recommended navigation markup from the Codex, using [`previous_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link) and [`next_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link):

```
<div class="navigation">
<div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Entries') ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Next Entries &raquo;','') ?></div>
</div>
```

See also, [this DigWP post on WordPress navigation](http://digwp.com/2009/08/wordpress-page-navigation/).

Comment: Thanks for your input, I always find your answers to be helpful. I've removed `query_posts()` as I've determined it to be not of any use or importance, yet my problem persists. Any ideas?

Comment: See updated answer. You need to provide navigation links. :)

Comment: I added the navigation links just before the end of the loop as well as just before `<?php endwhile; ?>`, still no posts being shown :/

Comment: Your blog posts index is showing all 40 posts: http://frshstudio.com/blog/ Check `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading` and verify your setting for # of posts to display per page. Also, what **Plugins** do you have active? Do you have any custom code in `functions.php` that may be modifying `posts_per_page`?